# View switches like google plus

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Any sample code like view switches like google plus, Nearby to Circles to Incomming?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this it's similar to what you want I think.

https://github.com/HubertK/OffsetScrollviews

Answer (score 4):

@Hubert i have made a few adjustments to your code, now you can scroll the topScrollView and move the bottomScrollView heres the code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
if (scrollView == self.bottomScrollView) {
    //i dont know where this number came from 2.46153846
    float bOffset =  self.bottomScrollView.contentOffset.x/2.66666666666667;
    NSLog(@"%f",self.bottomScrollView.contentOffset.x);
    NSLog(@"%f",self.topScrollView.contentOffset.x);
    CGPoint theOffset = CGPointMake(self.bottomScrollView.contentOffset.x, self.topScrollView.contentOffset.y);
    theOffset.x = bOffset;

    [self.topScrollView setContentOffset:theOffset animated:NO];
}
// if the TopScrollView is Moved
if (scrollView == self.topScrollView) {
    float bOffset =  self.topScrollView.contentOffset.x*2.66666666666667;
    CGPoint theOffset = CGPointMake(self.topScrollView.contentOffset.x, self.bottomScrollView.contentOffset.y);
    theOffset.x = bOffset;

    [self.bottomScrollView setContentOffset:theOffset animated:NO];
}
```

}

Comment: @Alex where is 2.66666666666667 came from?

Comment: ohh that was my mistake... if im not wrong... that was the size of scrollview divided in the size of view or something like that... but its wrong... the correct number is 2.46153846... sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this will help. Here Title2 view is added with animation and simultaneously Title1.view is removed. you can write similar code for right transition

```
-(void)handleLeftTransition:(id)sender
{


    if(![self.view.subviews containsObject:title2.view])
    {

    title2.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 20, 320, 350);
        [self.view addSubview:title2.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f 
                     animations:^{
                                 title2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 350);  
                         title1.view.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 20, 320, 350);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if([self.view.subviews containsObject:title1.view])
                             [title1.view removeFromSuperview];
                                             }];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

is [that](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) something like you are looking for?